# Spring: Autowired is null in ejb class

Tags: spring, ejb, repository, autowired, inject

I have the following situation:

```
    @Controller
    public class myController {
        @Autowired
        private IProxy service;

        public ModelAndView init(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
          List<String> list = service.getName();
        }
    }
```

Then my Service is define as follow:

```
public interface IProxy {
    public List<String> getName();
}
```

Proxy class is responsible for the lookup to the remote bean

```
@Service("service")
public class Proxy implements IProxy {
...
public List<String> getName() {
   return myClass.getName();
}
```

And the implementation is the following:

```
@Interceptors(interceptor.class)
@Stateless
@Resource(name = "java:/db")
@Remote(MyClassRemote.class)
public class MyClassImpl extends MyEjb implements MyClassRemote{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "db")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sctx;
    @Autowired
    public IMyRepo myRepo;

    @Override
    public List<String> getName() {
        try {
             return myRepo.getName(em);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {}
    }
```

So, the problem is that here myRepo is null. I don't know why because IMyRepo and his implementation are always located within the path scanned by Spring.

Just one clarification: MyRepo class that implements IMyRepo is annotated with @Repository.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring beans and EJB are two different things, you can't just inject a Spring bean in an EJB, because that EJB is no Spring bean, so Spring doesn't know there is a field which should be injected by Spring (unless you use some fancy AOP stuff, which can enable injection into non-Spring-managed beans).

Comment: Ok dunni. I understand the concept. Thank you very much

Comment: You can inject Spring beans in EJB , please refer to @Tarek answer just down bellow

Answer (score 3):

you can inject spring beans in EJB using Spring interceptors, as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html) in the official documentation. Basically you'll need to adjust your class as follows:

```
// added the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor class
@Interceptors({ interceptor.class, SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class })
@Stateless
@Resource(name = "java:/db")
@Remote(MyClassRemote.class)
public class MyClassImpl extends MyEjb implements MyClassRemote{
  // your code
}
```

You'll also need to define the context location in a beanRefContext.xml file (with your own application context file):

application-context.xml version

```
<bean id="context"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>application-context.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Java Configuration version:

```
<bean id="context"
    class="org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
        <value type="java.lang.Class">com.your.app.Configuration</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore with Spring 5. **SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor** support has been **removed**. Please check my solution for Spring >= v5 : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69342945/2971820)